# How to prevent jQuery click event firing on multiple elements at same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the above code which ideally will slide toggle the `ulContainer` but it doesn't work as expected. I would like it so when I click on the selector above, it only toggles one of the `ul#dropdown-download-links li > a` one click at a time. Currently, obviously it toggles them all on click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#dropdown-download-links li > a").unbind().click(function(e) {
    var ulContainer = $(this).closest("li");
    e.preventDefault();
    $(ulContainer).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dropdown-download-links">
  <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Toggle on click etc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">But don't toggle on click of first one</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I hope that makes sense, I feel like it's a super common probelm it's just hard to explain.

Comment: It's not clear from the HTML and code you have supplied what the issue is. Clicking on one of the `Test` links toggles just that `li` element.

Comment: No it toggles both, because the selector matches it. That's the problem, how do I toggle for each individual LI instead? Should I do an if statement, switch etc?

Comment: I've replaced the code in your question with a snippet; when you run that it seems to behave as you describe you want.

Comment: FYI: `ulContainer` is already a jQuery object, there is zero need to wrap it in a `$()` when you use it.

Comment: unclear how it toggles them all.... you mean if you click on the "Test" it also hides "Toggle on click etc" ???

Answer (score 2):

The event is bound on the 'a' element, to get and toggle the child items, you first need to go up one level with the 'parent()' method which returns the 'li' element. After that use the find method to get the child list items.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#dropdown-download-links li > a").unbind().click(function(e) {
        var ulContainer = $(this).parent().find("li");
        e.preventDefault();
        $(ulContainer).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dropdown-download-links">
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Toggle on click etc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Toggle on click etc</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">But don't toggle on click of first one</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul#dropdown-download-links li:first-child >a").unbind().click(function(e) {
    var ulContainer = $(this).closest("li");
    e.preventDefault();
    $(ulContainer).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="dropdown-download-links">
  <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Toggle on click etc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">But don't toggle on click of first one</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I only add  " first-child " with li .

ul#dropdown-download-links li:first-child >a